# Auto refresh the div

Tags: jquery

In that auto refresh i use another function ie ontime1();

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function my_function() {
        $('#show').load(location.href + '#show');
    }
    ontime1();
    setInterval(my_function, 2000);
</script>
```

It's nothing but,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    ontime1();
});
function ontime1() {
    $(".ontime1").css("background-color", "#FFA500");
}
```

Initially color will appear.after that it's blinking.how to maintain the color through out after refreshing also.

Comment: requirement is not clear

Comment: Add a code snippet that shows the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`

```
setTimeout(my_function, 2000);
```

`setInterval` fires again and again in intervals, while `setTimeout` only fires once.

Comment: I need to refresh every 5 seconds.So i can't use setTimeout

Comment: I am using table.This table under div.I need to refresh this table every 5 seconds.In my table i differenciate the rows using colors.Once i refresh the div the color is blinking.how to maintain the color after refresh also